# Import Multiple Pivot tables using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to automate the import of xml data that forms a pivot table in excel. To import the data a link is read/copied from one sheet and the results are reported on another sheet. The only problem with this methods I am manually doing this.

How can this macro

```
Sub retrieveXML2()
'
' pivotdataImport Macro
'

'
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= _
        "http://api.sba.gov/license_permit/all_by_state/al.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$2")
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A29").Select
    Sheets("url").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= _
        "http://api.sba.gov/license_permit/all_by_state/ak.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$29")
    Rows("29:29").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[count]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A59").Select
    Sheets("url").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= _
        "http://api.sba.gov/license_permit/all_by_state/az.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$59")
    Rows("59:59").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A60").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A85").Select
    Sheets("url").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= _
        "http://api.sba.gov/license_permit/all_by_state/ar.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$85")
    Rows("85:85").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A86").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A114").Select
    Sheets("url").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= _
        "http://api.sba.gov/license_permit/all_by_state/ca.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$114")
    Rows("114:114").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A115").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A141").Select
End Sub
```

be made to just perform these steps for any amount of url without actually placing them where they need to be?

My other macro

```
Public Sub retrieveXML()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlManual


    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strXML As String
    Dim ct As Integer, XMLMap

    Const maxXMLDel = 1
    lngRow = 2

    Do While Cells(lngRow, 1) <> ""
        strXML = Cells(lngRow, 1)
        ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:=strXML, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$B$" & lngRow)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        For Each XMLMap In ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps
                  XMLMap.Delete
        Next
      Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

does something similar; however it was designed for xml data that only would fill just a single row. So if I try to apply to xml data that forms a pivot table I am informed when it goes to the next url that data already exist in the cells already. So how could the second macro be made to do the actions of the recorded macro?

I would not know the table length, but would need for it to go underneath the previous table.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Create a single set of lines that happens each time, change the url and the target location for variables and have these read from a list in your excel sheet, now loop through this list in your excel sheet and apply the values in the set of lines.

Comment: when I run this macro I will do exactly as I want it to since it a a recorded macro. But I would like to be able to have a list of urls on the url sheet that are looped through and the results put on the data sheet without it indicating that data already exist there

Answer (score 0):

Create the list with urls and target ranges somewhere in your workbook, for example in the sheet "datalinks" in columns A and B.

```
Dim rInput As Range

Set rInput = Sheets("datalinks").Range("A2:B2") 
Do While not IsEmpty(rInput)

    '.... YOUR CODE

    ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMport url:= rInput.Cells(1,1).Value2 _ 
        , ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range(rInput.Cells(1,2).Value2)

    '.... YOUR CODE

    Set rInput = rInput.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

Comment: I was only able to determine the target ranges after I imported the table I would not know beforehand what the ranges of the additional tables would be. I would essentially only know the url and that a table is coming

Comment: You wouldnt know the top left cell of the range? If they are all coming next to eachother you could determine the right-most cell that contains the last imported table and use Offset(0, x) to put the new table in

Comment: but if I do as you indicate by putting the url down column A and then try to import the data down column B how is the table data that corresponds with the url/file going to stay with the url?

Comment: I dont say you import the data into column B, I said to put the target range (so for example the TEXT "A$A9" into column B)... See my code which should clarify it `rInput.Cells(1,1).Value2` contains the url String and `rInput.Cells(1,2).Value2` the destination cell coordinates as a String.